# CreateQuery method replacement in Realm 4.0

Tags: android, realm

With realm 4.0, createQuery method from RealmQuery class is deprecated. Now, how can I encapsulate a query and pass it to another method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`realm.where(MyObject.class)` returns a query.

But if you check the breaking changes, this is also mentioned there.

> RealmQuery.createQuery(Realm, Class), RealmQuery.createDynamicQuery(DynamicRealm, String), RealmQuery.createQueryFromResult(RealmResults) and RealmQuery.createQueryFromList(RealmList) have been removed.
>
> Use Realm.where(Class), DynamicRealm.where(String), RealmResults.where() and RealmList.where() instead.